# Solidus current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree, solidus

I am trying to add login/logout/sign up links to the front page of a solidus app. In the _login_bar_items partial I put this:

```
 <% if spree_current_user %>
 <li>
     <%= link_to "Logout", destroy_spree_user_session_path, method: :delete %>
   </li>
 <% else %>
   <li>
     <%= link_to "Login", new_spree_user_session_path %>
   </li>
   <li>
     <%= link_to "Register", new_spree_user_registration_path %>
   </li>
 <% end %>
```

And I get the error

```
No route matches [DELETE] "/user/spree_user/logout"
```

when I click on logout button. The paths are as displayed when I run `rails routes`.

I also tried `if current_user` but that didn't work either.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Edit: Rails Routes output:

```
  Prefix Verb URI Pattern                                                                                    Controller#Action
                spree      /                                                                                        Spree::Core::Engine
   rails_service_blob GET  /rails/active_storage/blobs/:signed_id/*filename(.:format)                               active_storage/blobs#show
  rails_blob_representation GET  /rails/active_storage/representations/:signed_blob_id/:variation_key/*filename(.:format)             active_storage/representations#show
   rails_disk_service GET  /rails/active_storage/disk/:encoded_key/*filename(.:format)                              active_storage/disk#show
  update_rails_disk_service PUT  /rails/active_storage/disk/:encoded_token(.:format)                                                              active_storage/disk#update
       rails_direct_uploads POST /rails/active_storage/direct_uploads(.:format)                                           active_storage/direct_uploads#create

  Routes for Spree::Core::Engine:
                                 new_spree_user_session GET    /user/spree_user/sign_in(.:format)                                                                       spree/user_sessions#new
                                     spree_user_session POST   /user/spree_user/sign_in(.:format)                                                                 spree/user_sessions#create
                             destroy_spree_user_session GET    /user/spree_user/logout(.:format)                                                                  spree/user_sessions#destroy
                                new_spree_user_password GET    /user/spree_user/password/new(.:format)                                                            spree/user_passwords#new
                               edit_spree_user_password GET    /user/spree_user/password/edit(.:format)                                                           spree/user_passwords#edit
                                    spree_user_password PATCH  /user/spree_user/password(.:format)                                                                spree/user_passwords#update
                                                        PUT    /user/spree_user/password(.:format)                                                                spree/user_passwords#update
                                                        POST   /user/spree_user/password(.:format)                                                                spree/user_passwords#create
                         cancel_spree_user_registration GET    /user/spree_user/cancel(.:format)                                                                  spree/user_registrations#cancel
                            new_spree_user_registration GET    /user/spree_user/sign_up(.:format)                                                                 spree/user_registrations#new
                           edit_spree_user_registration GET    /user/spree_user/edit(.:format)                                                                    spree/user_registrations#edit
                                spree_user_registration PATCH  /user/spree_user(.:format)                                                                         spree/user_registrations#update
                                                        PUT    /user/spree_user(.:format)                                                                         spree/user_registrations#update
                                                        DELETE /user/spree_user(.:format)                                                                         spree/user_registrations#destroy
                                                        POST   /user/spree_user(.:format)                                                                         spree/user_registrations#create
                            new_spree_user_confirmation GET    /user/spree_user/confirmation/new(.:format)                                                        spree/user_confirmations#new
                                spree_user_confirmation GET    /user/spree_user/confirmation(.:format)                                                            spree/user_confirmations#show
                                                        POST   /user/spree_user/confirmation(.:format)                                                            spree/user_confirmations#create
                                              edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                                                                          spree/users#edit
                                                   user PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)                                                                               spree/users#update
                                                        PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                                                                               spree/users#update
                                                  login GET    /login(.:format)                                                                                   spree/user_sessions#new
                                     create_new_session POST   /login(.:format)                                                                                   spree/user_sessions#create
                                                 logout GET    /logout(.:format)                                                                                  spree/user_sessions#destroy
                                                 signup GET    /signup(.:format)                                                                                  spree/user_registrations#new
                                           registration POST   /signup(.:format)                                                                                  spree/user_registrations#create
                                       recover_password GET    /password/recover(.:format)                                                                        spree/user_passwords#new
                                         reset_password POST   /password/recover(.:format)                                                                        spree/user_passwords#create
                                          edit_password GET    /password/change(.:format)                                                                         spree/user_passwords#edit
                                        update_password PUT    /password/change(.:format)                                                                         spree/user_passwords#update
                                           confirmation GET    /confirm(.:format)                                                                                 spree/user_confirmations#show
                                  checkout_registration GET    /checkout/registration(.:format)                                                                   spree/checkout#registration
                           update_checkout_registration PUT    /checkout/registration(.:format)                                                                   spree/checkout#update_registration
                                            new_account GET    /account/new(.:format)                                                                             spree/users#new
                                           edit_account GET    /account/edit(.:format)                                                                            spree/users#edit
                                                account GET    /account(.:format)                                                                                 spree/users#show
                                                        PATCH  /account(.:format)                                                                                 spree/users#update
                                                        PUT    /account(.:format)                                                                                 spree/users#update
                                                        DELETE /account(.:format)                                                                                 spree/users#destroy
                                                        POST   /account(.:format)                                                                                 spree/users#create
                                     admin_unauthorized GET    /admin/authorization_failure(.:format)                                                             spree/admin/user_sessions#authorization_failure
                                            admin_login GET    /admin/login(.:format)                                                                             spree/admin/user_sessions#new
                               admin_create_new_session POST   /admin/login(.:format)                                                                             spree/admin/user_sessions#create
                                           admin_logout GET    /admin/logout(.:format)                                                                            spree/admin/user_sessions#destroy
                                 admin_recover_password GET    /admin/password/recover(.:format)                                                                  spree/admin/user_passwords#new
                                   admin_reset_password POST   /admin/password/recover(.:format)                                                                  spree/admin/user_passwords#create
                                    admin_edit_password GET    /admin/password/change(.:format)                                                                   spree/admin/user_passwords#edit
                                  admin_update_password PUT    /admin/password/change(.:format)                                                                   spree/admin/user_passwords#update
                                                   root GET    /                                                                                                  spree/home#index
                                               products GET    /products(.:format)                                                                                spree/products#index
                                                product GET    /products/:id(.:format)                                                                            spree/products#show
                                             locale_set GET    /locale/set(.:format)                                                                              spree/locale#set
                                          select_locale POST   /locale/set(.:format)                                                                              spree/locale#set
                                        update_checkout PATCH  /checkout/update/:state(.:format)                                                                  spree/checkout#update
                                         checkout_state GET    /checkout/:state(.:format)                                                                         spree/checkout#edit
                                               checkout GET    /checkout(.:format)                                                                                spree/checkout#edit
                                        orders_populate GET    /orders/populate(.:format)                                                                         spree/orders#populate_redirect
                                            token_order GET    /orders/:id/token/:token(.:format)                                                                 spree/orders#show
                                        populate_orders POST   /orders/populate(.:format)                                                                         spree/orders#populate
                                             edit_order GET    /orders/:id/edit(.:format)                                                                         spree/orders#edit
                                                  order GET    /orders/:id(.:format)                                                                              spree/orders#show
                                                        PATCH  /orders/:id(.:format)                                                                              spree/orders#update
                                                        PUT    /orders/:id(.:format)                                                                              spree/orders#update
                                                   cart GET    /cart(.:format)                                                                                    spree/orders#edit
                                            update_cart PATCH  /cart(.:format)                                                                                    spree/orders#update
                                             empty_cart PUT    /cart/empty(.:format)                                                                              spree/orders#empty
                                          nested_taxons GET    /t/*id(.:format)                                                                                   spree/taxons#show
                                           unauthorized GET    /unauthorized(.:format)                                                                            spree/home#unauthorized
                                                    cvv GET    /content/cvv(.:format)                                                                             spree/content#cvv
                                              cart_link GET    /cart_link(.:format)                                                                               spree/store#cart_link
                                     admin_search_users GET    /admin/search/users(.:format)                                                                      spree/admin/search#users
                                  admin_search_products GET    /admin/search/products(.:format)                                                                   spree/admin/search#products
                                       admin_set_locale PUT    /admin/locale/set(.:format)                                                                        spree/admin/locale#set {:format=>:json}
                                  home_admin_dashboards GET    /admin/dashboards/home(.:format)                                                                   spree/admin/dashboards#home
                        admin_promotion_promotion_rules GET    /admin/promotions/:promotion_id/promotion_rules(.:format)                                          spree/admin/promotion_rules#index
                                                        POST   /admin/promotions/:promotion_id/promotion_rules(.:format)                                          spree/admin/promotion_rules#create
                     new_admin_promotion_promotion_rule GET    /admin/promotions/:promotion_id/promotion_rules/new(.:format)                                      spree/admin/promotion_rules#new
                    edit_admin_promotion_promotion_rule GET    /admin/promotions/:promotion_id/promotion_rules/:id/edit(.:format)                                 spree/admin/promotion_rules#edit
                         admin_promotion_promotion_rule GET    /admin/promotions/:promotion_id/promotion_rules/:id(.:format)                                      spree/admin/promotion_rules#show
                                                        PATCH  /admin/promotions/:promotion_id/promotion_rules/:id(.:format)                                      spree/admin/promotion_rules#update
                                                        PUT    /admin/promotions/:promotion_id/promotion_rules/:id(.:format)                                      spree/admin/promotion_rules#update
                                                        DELETE /admin/promotions/:promotion_id/promotion_rules/:id(.:format)                                      spree/admin/promotion_rules#destroy
                      admin_promotion_promotion_actions GET    /admin/promotions/:promotion_id/promotion_actions(.:format)                                        spree/admin/promotion_actions#index
                                                        POST   /admin/promotions/:promotion_id/promotion_actions(.:format)                                        spree/admin/promotion_actions#create
                   new_admin_promotion_promotion_action GET    /admin/promotions/:promotion_id/promotion_actions/new(.:format)                                    spree/admin/promotion_actions#new
                  edit_admin_promotion_promotion_action GET    /admin/promotions/:promotion_id/promotion_actions/:id/edit(.:format)                               spree/admin/promotion_actions#edit
                       admin_promotion_promotion_action GET    /admin/promotions/:promotion_id/promotion_actions/:id(.:format)                                    spree/admin/promotion_actions#show
                                                        PATCH  /admin/promotions/:promotion_id/promotion_actions/:id(.:format)                                    spree/admin/promotion_actions#update
                                                        PUT    /admin/promotions/:promotion_id/promotion_actions/:id(.:format)                                    spree/admin/promotion_actions#update
                                                        DELETE /admin/promotions/:promotion_id/promotion_actions/:id(.:format)                                    spree/admin/promotion_actions#destroy
                        admin_promotion_promotion_codes GET    /admin/promotions/:promotion_id/promotion_codes(.:format)                                          spree/admin/promotion_codes#index
          admin_promotion_promotion_code_batch_download GET    /admin/promotions/:promotion_id/promotion_code_batches/:promotion_code_batch_id/download(.:format) spree/admin/promotion_code_batches#download {:format=>"csv"}
                 admin_promotion_promotion_code_batches GET    /admin/promotions/:promotion_id/promotion_code_batches(.:format)                                   spree/admin/promotion_code_batches#index
                                                        POST   /admin/promotions/:promotion_id/promotion_code_batches(.:format)                                   spree/admin/promotion_code_batches#create
               new_admin_promotion_promotion_code_batch GET    /admin/promotions/:promotion_id/promotion_code_batches/new(.:format)                               spree/admin/promotion_code_batches#new
                                       admin_promotions GET    /admin/promotions(.:format)                                                                        spree/admin/promotions#index
                                                        POST   /admin/promotions(.:format)                                                                        spree/admin/promotions#create
                                    new_admin_promotion GET    /admin/promotions/new(.:format)                                                                    spree/admin/promotions#new
                                   edit_admin_promotion GET    /admin/promotions/:id/edit(.:format)                                                               spree/admin/promotions#edit
                                        admin_promotion GET    /admin/promotions/:id(.:format)                                                                    spree/admin/promotions#show
                                                        PATCH  /admin/promotions/:id(.:format)                                                                    spree/admin/promotions#update
                                                        PUT    /admin/promotions/:id(.:format)                                                                    spree/admin/promotions#update
                                                        DELETE /admin/promotions/:id(.:format)                                                                    spree/admin/promotions#destroy
                             admin_promotion_categories GET    /admin/promotion_categories(.:format)                                                              spree/admin/promotion_categories#index
                                                        POST   /admin/promotion_categories(.:format)                                                              spree/admin/promotion_categories#create
                           new_admin_promotion_category GET    /admin/promotion_categories/new(.:format)                                                          spree/admin/promotion_categories#new
                          edit_admin_promotion_category GET    /admin/promotion_categories/:id/edit(.:format)                                                     spree/admin/promotion_categories#edit
                               admin_promotion_category PATCH  /admin/promotion_categories/:id(.:format)                                                          spree/admin/promotion_categories#update
                                                        PUT    /admin/promotion_categories/:id(.:format)                                                          spree/admin/promotion_categories#update
                                                        DELETE /admin/promotion_categories/:id(.:format)                                                          spree/admin/promotion_categories#destroy
                                            admin_zones GET    /admin/zones(.:format)                                                                             spree/admin/zones#index
                                                        POST   /admin/zones(.:format)                                                                             spree/admin/zones#create
                                         new_admin_zone GET    /admin/zones/new(.:format)                                                                         spree/admin/zones#new
                                        edit_admin_zone GET    /admin/zones/:id/edit(.:format)                                                                    spree/admin/zones#edit
                                             admin_zone GET    /admin/zones/:id(.:format)                                                                         spree/admin/zones#show
                                                        PATCH  /admin/zones/:id(.:format)                                                                         spree/admin/zones#update
                                                        PUT    /admin/zones/:id(.:format)                                                                         spree/admin/zones#update
                                                        DELETE /admin/zones/:id(.:format)                                                                         spree/admin/zones#destroy
                                   admin_tax_categories GET    /admin/tax_categories(.:format)                                                                    spree/admin/tax_categories#index
                                                        POST   /admin/tax_categories(.:format)                                                                    spree/admin/tax_categories#create
                                 new_admin_tax_category GET    /admin/tax_categories/new(.:format)                                                                spree/admin/tax_categories#new
                                edit_admin_tax_category GET    /admin/tax_categories/:id/edit(.:format)                                                           spree/admin/tax_categories#edit
                                     admin_tax_category GET    /admin/tax_categories/:id(.:format)                                                                spree/admin/tax_categories#show
                                                        PATCH  /admin/tax_categories/:id(.:format)                                                                spree/admin/tax_categories#update
                                                        PUT    /admin/tax_categories/:id(.:format)                                                                spree/admin/tax_categories#update
```

Comment: can you add the output to rails routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
<%= link_to "Logout", destroy_spree_user_session_path %>
```

because your "/user/spree_user/logout" is not defined as DELETE request but as GET request route.